# itms-apps link displays old version

Tags: ios, app-store, mobile-application

Often times the link to my iOS app `itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/<my-app-id>` will open a stale version of the page in the `App Store`. Restarting the App Store or going to the Updates tab fixes the issue but one can't expect users to know that. Is there a parameter we can pass to the `itms-apps` URL to force a refresh?

Comment: Try to refresh App Store with [this trick](https://lifehacker.com/force-refresh-the-ios-app-store-by-tapping-the-tab-bar-1750465871) and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks for the hack but this is a problem my users are facing. So hoping for a programatic fix for the issue. Essentially need to either update the app page or redirect user to Updates tab.